# How can I maintain the call stack when I throw an exception from a thread in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception

**UPDATE 1**

We run some large threads (threads with lots of code). We're not getting a reliable call stack that points us to the exception being thrown.

To make this example more reproducible and simpler, I boiled down the code to the following. I also removed the requirements of using /EHa and VS2013. This code is being compiled with VS2015 (v140) and default exception handling. **I'm trying to figure out why the call stack doesn't ever seem to include the line that the std::runtime_error is thrown from.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void myLongRunningMethod()
{
    // Imagine lots of code here. We need to know where the exception
    // is being thrown. Just knowing that it was thrown from this thread
    // isn't sufficient.
    std::cout << "..throwing from myLongRunningMethod()" << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error("Test throw of std::runtime_error from thread"); // We would like to see this line in the call stack. We don't :(.
}

void main()
{
    std::cout << "in main()" << std::endl;

    // Spin up a thread and have it throw
    std::cout << ".spinning up a thread" << std::endl;
    std::thread t1(&myLongRunningMethod);

    // Wait for thread to complete
    std::cout << "...joining" << std::endl;
    t1.join();
    std::cout << "....join complete" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:
in main()
.spinning up a thread
..throwing from myLongRunningMethod()
...joining

Then I am presented with the abort() dialog. I click 'Retry'. Here is the callstack I get:

```
ucrtbased.dll!issue_debug_notification(const wchar_t * const message) Line 125  C++  
ucrtbased.dll!__acrt_report_runtime_error(const wchar_t * message) Line 142 C++  
ucrtbased.dll!abort() Line 51   C++  
ucrtbased.dll!terminate() Line 59   C++  
vcruntime140d.dll!FindHandler(EHExceptionRecord * pExcept, EHRegistrationNode * pRN, _CONTEXT * pContext, void * pDC, const _s_FuncInfo * pFuncInfo, unsigned char recursive, int CatchDepth, EHRegistrationNode * pMarkerRN) Line 714  C++  
vcruntime140d.dll!__InternalCxxFrameHandler(EHExceptionRecord * pExcept, EHRegistrationNode * pRN, _CONTEXT * pContext, void * pDC, const _s_FuncInfo * pFuncInfo, int CatchDepth, EHRegistrationNode * pMarkerRN, unsigned char recursive) Line 439    C++  
vcruntime140d.dll!__CxxFrameHandler(EHExceptionRecord * pExcept, EHRegistrationNode * pRN, void * pContext, void * pDC) Line 233    C++  
ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler2@20()  Unknown  
ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler@20()   Unknown  
EhTestProject.exe!std::_Invoker_functor::_Call<void (__cdecl*)(void)>(void(*)() && _Obj) Line 1375  C++  
EhTestProject.exe!std::_Pad::_Call_func(void * _Data) Line 209  C++  
ucrtbased.dll!invoke_thread_procedure(unsigned int(__stdcall*)(void *) procedure, void * const context) Line 92 C++  
ucrtbased.dll!thread_start<unsigned int (__stdcall*)(void *)>(void * const parameter) Line 115  C++  
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown  
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown  
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown
```

**FURTHER UNDERSTANDING**

I figured out why I was getting two dialog boxes (the main thread and the worker thread were each producing one). This was solved by adding a .join call to the main thread. Also, I do expect the thread to terminate on an unhandled exception (which explains why two of the three catch... blocks weren't getting entered).

**ORIGINAL POST**

Here's some code that isn't giving me the call stack I would expect and I'm unsure why. I've tried various combinations of try/catch without getting a full call stack.

- I can't use the solution where std::current_exception is stored off
  in a global because the threads in question are long running and we
  don't join them to our main process.
- We must use Async exception handling (/EHa), so a catch(...) block
  will catch structured exceptions as well as standard exceptions, thus
  treating all exceptions caught in a catch(...) block as fatal.
- I can only use feautres supported by the v120 (2013) Microsoft C++ compiler.

Ideally, I want a full call stack to debug with. I'm having trouble figuring out why/how call stacks are being sliced.

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Main.cpp
#include "OtherDll.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <windows.h>

LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER topLevelEF = nullptr;
static bool exceptionIsHandled = false;

LONG WINAPI UnhandledExceptionFilter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS p)
{
    std::cout << "....in UnhandledExceptionFilter (exceptionIsHandled = " << exceptionIsHandled << ")" << std::endl;

    // Handle exception (in case the top-level try catch missed it)

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

void main()
{
    // Microsoft best practice is to call SetErrorMode()
    ::SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
    ::SetThreadErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS, nullptr);

    // Setup the process global unhandled exception filter to be called for an unhandled exception occurs
    topLevelEF = ::SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(UnhandledExceptionFilter);

    std::cout << "in main()" << std::endl;

    auto otherDll = std::make_unique<OtherDll>();

    try
    {
        otherDll->throwStdRuntimeExceptionFromThread();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "..caught(...) in main(). Rethrowing with throw." << std::endl;
        exceptionIsHandled = true;

        throw;
    }

    system("pause"); // Windows specific
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// OtherDll.h
#pragma once

#ifndef OTHERDLL_API
#define OTHERDLL_API
#endif

class OtherDll
{
public:
    OTHERDLL_API OtherDll();

    static OTHERDLL_API void throwStdRuntimeExceptionFromThread();

private:
    static void myPrivateThrowMethod();
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// OtherDll.cpp
#define OTHERDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#include "OtherDll.h"

#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

OtherDll::OtherDll()
{
    std::cout << "..in OtherDll CTOR" << std::endl;
}

void OtherDll::throwStdRuntimeExceptionFromThread()
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "....calling thread to throw from try" << std::endl;
        std::thread t1(&OtherDll::myPrivateThrowMethod);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "......in catch(...)" << std::endl;

        // handle exception

        throw; //crash the process
    }
}

void OtherDll::myPrivateThrowMethod()
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "......throwing from thread try" << std::endl;
        throw std::runtime_error("Test from thread");
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "......caught by thread catch(...). Rethrowing." << std::endl;

        throw; // must always rethrow because catching SEH (like access violations that are unrecoverable)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

in main()
..in OtherDll CTOR
....calling thread to throw from try
......throwing from thread try
......caught by thread catch(...). Rethrowing.

At this point a 'Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library' dialog pops up telling me that abort() has been called. I click Retry to debug the application. I then get the next line of output from my program:

....in UnhandledExceptionFilter (exceptionIsHandled = 0)

To add to my confusion, sometimes I get two of the aforementioned VisualC++ dialog boxes. Also, sometimes (very rarely)...it does give me the call stack I would expect. Here are the two call stacks I'll get:

**99% of the time (not helpful):**
    msvcr120d.dll!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum) Line 226    C
    msvcr120d.dll!abort() Line 62   C
    msvcr120d.dll!terminate() Line 97   C++
    msvcp120d.dll!_Call_func(void * _Data) Line 39  C++
    msvcr120d.dll!_callthreadstartex() Line 376 C
    msvcr120d.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd) Line 359   C
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown

**1% of the time (good stack):**
    MSVCR120D.dll!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum) Line 226    C
    MSVCR120D.dll!abort() Line 62   C
    MSVCR120D.dll!terminate() Line 97   C++
    OtherDll.dll!std::thread::~thread() Line 56 C++
    OtherDll.dll!OtherDll::throwStdRuntimeExceptionFromThread() Line 47 C++
    EhTestProject.exe!main() Line 47    C++

Comment: It seems to me that there is a timing issue that is causing your two different behaviors.  If your new thread manages to throw its exception and get caught before OtherDll::throwStdRuntimeExceptionFromThread() unwinds on the main thread, then you get your 99% case.  However, if the aforementioned function unwinds on main thread first, then std::thread destructor appears to be throwing an exception of its own to get the 1% case.

Comment: @qexyn You're right that the thread is unwinding itself sometimes and throwing it's own exception, which calls terminate, invoking the UnhandledExceptionFilter, and finally ending up with a good call stack. I'm still unclear how to get this call stack reliably. I'm also unsure why I'm getting two pop-ups, it's as if the main thread and the worker thread are crashing at the same time. I'm still left at the end of the day without a call stack that shows the throwStdRuntimeExceptionFromThread() line 99% of the time.

Comment: I can only guess that the two dialogs result from the two threads almost simultaneously calling abort().  To solve your actual problem though, you should either call join on your thread object (this will block until thread completion) or call detach (this will return immediately and indicates that your thread object should no longer manage the underlying resource, essentially).  The lack of doing one of those things is causing your std::thread destructor to call terminate(): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread